# Can't get desired data from HTML source string C#

Tags: c#, html, webclient, html-agility-pack

I need to get currency values from https://www.bcr.ro/en/exchange-rates but getting html string with these methods:

1. ```
   WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.bcr.ro/en/exchange-rates");
   req.Method = "GET";

   string source;
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
   {
       source = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   ```
2. ```
   WebClient wc = new WebClient();
   string s = wc.DownloadString("https://www.bcr.ro/en/exchange-rates");
   ```

Both are resulting in getting a weird html string, which not contains desired data:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  lang="en" class="no-js false_EAM isEmil_false">
<!-- Version: 2.16.7.0 (gportals2m1pvm1-044457035960000082024075) Date: 24.10.2015 18:19:59 -->
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Exchange rates | BCR</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://www.bcr.ro/content/8ea9dd8a/-3b9c-429b-9f72-34e75b7512e3/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="author" content="Banca Comerciala Romana (BCR): loans, cards, deposits, Internet Banking, current account">
  <meta name="description" content="Banca Comerciala Romana (BCR), a member of Erste Group, is a universal bank serving both retail and corporate clients. ">
  <meta name="generator" content="Group Portal - 2.16.7.0"><meta name="keywords" content=" loans, cards, deposits, Internet Banking, current account">
```

How could I achieve wanted result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a quick research, the answer is pretty simple:

1. Both `WebRequest` and `WebClient` with [initiallink](http://%22https://www.bcr.ro/en/exchange-rates%22) pull the data contained in source of page which is <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, which  does not contain desired data
2. After a quick search in DEV (<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>) it was clear that desired data was  brought dynamically, so after a look in Network TAB I found the request ([data](https://www.bcr.ro/bin/erstegroup/fx?institute=785)) which was pulling exact desired data in a beautiful JSON (perfect).

Answer (score -1):

Try to create a RegEx that grabs this out (`'<table class="overview glaze fullsize">'`) and then grabs everything in this tag of the HTML page. Then use it where needed.